# Distances on Earth: which python package is closest to geographic measurements?

Tags: library, python, geography

## Context

In the answers of the post [How to use GeoSeries.distance to get the right answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293310/how-to-use-geoseries-distance-to-get-the-right-answer/293342), the distance between two points on Earth is computed with two packages:

- [geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) : [479.450134 meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293310/how-to-use-geoseries-distance-to-get-the-right-answer/293342#293342) according to @CJ Xu's answer edited by @Tal Weiss
- [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) : [480.04157836 meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293310/how-to-use-geoseries-distance-to-get-the-right-answer/293342#293342) according to @virtuvious
  The difference between the answers is less 1 meter which is small compared to the diameter of the earth (~12 742 km). But it is still a little over .1% of the average distance.

## Question

What is the most accurate (closest to geographical observations) python package to measure point to point distances on Earth ?

I'm opened to other libraries than geopandas and geopy